# Rails Admin manageable static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an app running on rails 5.1, I need the admin of the site to be able to edit static elements such as Backgrounds, Texts and Colors.
For example titles and images on pages such as home, about us, help and more..

I was thinking of creating a Page Model with multiple images, texts, and strings that wouldn't have a way for any user to add new records, only to edit existing ones. Then render each individually on their respective places, for example rendering the home page title as (on home/index.erb):

```
<%= Page.find(id: 0).texts[0] %>
```

But this seems overly complicated, specially in terms of maintainability and integration with gems such as active-admin. Is there a better practice?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin can be used for this, but I think you really want a CMS, see https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/content_management_systems